# Desciprtion Function In Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I learning  android programming and in my first step I want to know what each function do
I discovered that all description about the function is found in activity.class.
IS my information right?
if it right I have a problem in activity.class in eclipse 
and the error msg is the source attachment doesn't contain the source for the file Activity.class
what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the information, that you need to know about activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html